# Deployment processing phase failed : Fatal error - unable to load storageManagerFactory

Tags: publishing, deployer, publishingfailed, transport

Publishing is failing at Deploying stage. In the CMS, the error message says:
`Phase: Deployment processing phase failel.null.Fatal error - unable to load storageManagerFactory`.

Checked the cm server for logs - in cd_core_logs , I could see the below error logged :

Updated it with the correct ones

ERROR HTTPSTransportConnector - Unable to execute File retrieval on destination: http://servername:81/HTTPUpload.aspx
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://servername:81 refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:158) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:150) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:575) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.HTTPSTransportConnector.retrieveFileIfPresent(HTTPSTransportConnector.java:247) ~[cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.TransportPoolConnector.retrieveFileIfPresent(TransportPoolConnector.java:80) [cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.workers.EndpointMetaWorker.getMetadata(EndpointMetaWorker.java:54) [cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.DestinationController.run(DestinationController.java:217) [cd_transport.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:123) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
    ... 12 common frames omitted

Tridion version - 2013 Sp1
Protocal used - https

I am not able to identify which access is being denied , because no config changes have been done. Please suggest.

Comment: Could you **edit** your question and provide a bit more detail about your setup/configuration and share what version of Tridion/SDL Web you are using? Looking at the error it seems you are using FTP transport and the FTP server is simply denying access so that sounds like the credentials used in the Publication Target Destination are incorrect (or perhaps expired).

Comment: Have you checked the connectivity between the publisher and the deployer? Does the url http://servername:81/HTTPUpload.aspx returns the expected response?

Comment: Please self answer the question as suggested here https://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer, that way the question can be considered "closed" once you accepted the answer, and it will contain useful information for people who might encounter the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to update , the issue was resolved by clearing the Transaction folder in Tridion Home directory .Due to continuous publishing , the transaction folder was not cleared in enough time and hence the issue occured.